# Access denied error while trying to connect Spyder on Windows to remote python kernel

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I'm trying to connect my Spyder IDE(on Windows 7) to a remote python kernel. I have a ssh key file, and I enter the server name like "username@sftp_url:portnumber" and also enter the password. But when I try to connect, I get this weird access denied error:

```
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1110, in create_client_for_kernel
    password)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1781, in _create_client_for_kernel
    kernel_client.load_connection_file()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 493, in load_connection_file
    with open(connection_file) as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\username\\Recent'
```

I have tried to set read/write permissions on "recent" folder, although I have no idea why python needs to write to that folder, bu the problem persists.
Any ideas?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I don't know why this error happens by my suggestion is for you to install Anaconda from `ProgramData` and install it for your user only. That way you should avoid this error.

Comment: Hi @CarlosCordoba , thanks for the reply. I did just what you said. Installed all instances of Anaconda and installed Anaconda 3 again in users/username/documents/anaconda only for myself, but still get the exact same error!

Comment: I've got the same error on Windows 10 with Spyder 3.2.3. Is there any update on this issue ?

Comment: @Melike unfortunately, no. My problem wasn't resolved in the end